# Issue with undefined collection in Backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, collections, requirejs

I have a router that renders a backbone view.  (I am using requirejs also)

```
    initialize: function () {
        var crateCollection = new CrateCollection();
        crateCollection.fetch({
            success: function()
            {
                var cratesView = new CratesView({ model: crateCollection });
            }
        });
    }
```

In the initialization of the view the collection is all fine and I can output it to console.log and see that it is appropriately populated.

```
    initialize: function (models) {
        var crateCollection = models.model;
        console.log(crateCollection);
        this.render();
    }
```

However, when I run the render function the crateCollection is undefined and the JS errors with an "can't access models of undefined"

```
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        var that = this;
        console.log(this.crateCollection);
        _.each(this.crateCollection.models, function (item) {
            that.renderCrate(item);
        }, this);
    },
```

Why would this collection not be accessible from this function?  It should definitely be populated as it waits for the async call to come back successful before it initializes the view, so their shouldn't be any issue there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `initialize` of `View` use

```
this.crateCollection = models.model;
```

instead of

```
var crateCollection = models.model;
```

i think there is a scope issue of `crateCollection`.

Comment: Thank you!!  I knew it was a scope issue, but couldn't work out why. ;-)